# iOS Speech Recognition crash on installTapOnBus - [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:911:SetOutputFormat: (format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate)]

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Most times I launch the app, the test-to-speech audio and speech recognition work perfectly. But sometimes I launch it and it crashes when first starting speech recognition. It seems to get on a roll and crash several launches in a row, so it is a little bit consistent, once it gets into one of its 'moods' :)

The recognition starts after a TTS introduction and at the same time as TTS says 'listening' - therefore both are active at once. Possibly the audio takes a few milliseconds to change over and gets crashy, but I am not clear how this works or how to prevent it.

I see the following error:

```
[avae] AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: 
[AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:911:SetOutputFormat: (format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate)]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', 
reason: 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'
```

I have put some `try-catches` in, just to see if it prevents this error and it doesn't. I also added a tiny `sleep` which also made no difference. So I am not even clear which code is causing it. If I put a breakpoint before the `removeTapOnBus` code, it does not crash until this line executes. If I put the breakpoint on the `installTapOnBus` line it does not crash until that line. And if I put the breakpoint after the code, it crashes. So it does seem to be this code.

In any case, what am I doing wrong or how could I debug it?

```
- (void) recordAndRecognizeWithLang:(NSString *) lang
    {
        NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:lang];
        self.sfSpeechRecognizer = [[SFSpeechRecognizer alloc] initWithLocale:locale];
        if (!self.sfSpeechRecognizer) {
            [self sendErrorWithMessage:@"The language is not supported" andCode:7];
        } else {

            // Cancel the previous task if it's running.
            if ( self.recognitionTask ) {
                [self.recognitionTask cancel];
                self.recognitionTask = nil;
            }

            //[self initAudioSession];

            self.recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
            self.recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = [[self.command argumentAtIndex:1] boolValue];

            // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizerdelegate
            // only callback is availabilityDidChange
            self.sfSpeechRecognizer.delegate = self;      

            self.recognitionTask = [self.sfSpeechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:self.recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult *result, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"recognise");

                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"error %ld", error.code);
                    // code 1 or 203 or 216 = we called abort via self.recognitionTask cancel
                    // 1101 is thrown when in simulator
                    // 1700 is when not given permission
                    if (error.code==203){   //|| error.code==216
                        // nothing, carry on, this is bullshit, or maybe not...
                        [self sendErrorWithMessage:@"sfSpeechRecognizer Error" andCode:error.code];
                    }else{
                        [self stopAndRelease];
                        // note: we can't send error back to js as I found it crashes (when recognising, then switch apps, then come back)
                        [self sendErrorWithMessage:@"sfSpeechRecognizer Error" andCode:error.code];
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (result) {
                    NSMutableArray * alternatives = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    int maxAlternatives = [[self.command argumentAtIndex:2] intValue];
                    for ( SFTranscription *transcription in result.transcriptions ) {
                        if (alternatives.count < maxAlternatives) {
                            float confMed = 0;
                            for ( SFTranscriptionSegment *transcriptionSegment in transcription.segments ) {
                                //NSLog(@"transcriptionSegment.confidence %f", transcriptionSegment.confidence);
                                if (transcriptionSegment.confidence){
                                    confMed +=transcriptionSegment.confidence;
                                }
                            }
                            NSLog(@"transcriptionSegment.transcript %@", transcription.formattedString);

                            NSMutableDictionary * resultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                            [resultDict setValue:transcription.formattedString forKey:@"transcript"];
                            [resultDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:result.isFinal] forKey:@"final"];
                            float conf = 0;
                            if (confMed && transcription.segments && transcription.segments.count && transcription.segments.count>0){
                                conf = confMed/transcription.segments.count;
                            }
                            [resultDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:conf]forKey:@"confidence"];
                            [alternatives addObject:resultDict];
                        }
                    }
                    [self sendResults:@[alternatives]];
                    if ( result.isFinal ) {
                        //NSLog(@"recog: isFinal");
                        [self stopAndRelease];
                    }
                }
            }];

            //[self.audioEngine.inputNode disconnectNodeInput:0];
            AVAudioFormat *recordingFormat = [self.audioEngine.inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];
            //AVAudioFormat *recordingFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:44100 channels:1];
            NSLog(@"samplerate=%f", recordingFormat.sampleRate);
            NSLog(@"channelCount=%i", recordingFormat.channelCount);

            // tried this but does not prevent crashing
            //if (recordingFormat.sampleRate <= 0) {
            //    [self.audioEngine.inputNode reset];
            //    recordingFormat = [[self.audioEngine inputNode] outputFormatForBus:0];
            //}

            sleep(1);  // to prevent random crashes
            @try {
                [self.audioEngine.inputNode removeTapOnBus:0];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"removeTapOnBus exception");
            }

            sleep(1);  // to prevent random crashes
            @try {
                NSLog(@"install tap on bus");
                [self.audioEngine.inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:recordingFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
                    //NSLog(@"tap");
                    [self.recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
                }];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"installTapOnBus exception");
            }

            sleep(1);  // to prevent random crashes
            [self.audioEngine prepare];
            NSError* error = nil;
            BOOL isOK = [self.audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error];
            if (!isOK){
                NSLog(@"audioEngine startAndReturnError returned false");
            }
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"audioEngine startAndReturnError error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you create a bug report on https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ ? Because if it says _uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio'_, it may need investigation by Apple. Feel free to share the Feedback number.

Comment: I don't think I have enough of a reproducible case to file a bug